# heroku rake db:migrate is not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I do `rake db:migrate`, I get the error,below i have attached my databse.yml and my gem file, tried all the stuff on the internet but the error did'nt get resolved!

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: demo_project_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: localhost
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: demo_project_test
  database: db/development.mysql2
  username: root
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: demo_project_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Gemfile
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
end

gem 'spring'
gem 'devise'
gem "cancan"
gem 'ckeditor', '4.1.3'
gem "nested_form"
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.0.0"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'ratyrate'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.6'
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
end
```

Below is my application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module DemoProject
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
    config.api_only = false
  end
end
```

config/envoirment.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
Rails.application.initialize!
```

boot.rb

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

Comment: Do you have the mysql gems added to your gemfile?  Did you run bundle install?

Comment: Ya i have,  and i also did bundle install

Comment: You are getting this error in your machine or heroku ? Are you running `heroku run rake db:migrate` ? And as far as I know, Heroku does not support mysql, it only supports Postgresql.

Comment: I am getting this on my machine, i know heroku only supports postgresql

Comment: Your question and title suggests that the error is on Heroku, not your local machine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error in a dummy Rails 4.2.6 app with your `Gemfile` and `database.yml`. I couldn't even push the app to Heroku without raising `LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql2`.

I fixed the problem by removing the `mysql2` gem from the development and test groups and adding it to the default group. My guess is that running `bundle install` locally adds it as a dependency to `Gemfile.lock` which is checked into git and pushed to Heroku. Heroku doesn't install the gem and when the app tries to require it a `LoadError` is raised.

```
group :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
```

A couple notes: if you want to add one gem to two or more specific groups, do not specify them separately. This just means there are two places where you're going to have to remember to change your version dependencies. So instead of this

```
group :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'another_gem'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'another_gem'
end
```

do this

```
group :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'another_gem'
end
```

Also, you shouldn't use MySQL locally and PostgreSQL in production, just use Postgres for both. They are not fully compatible, so you are bound to run into confusing issues down the road. Your best solution to this problem would be to remove `mysql2` altogether and configure your dev and test databases for Postgres.

Comment: I fixed spaces issue, but still getting the same error

Comment: After committing and pushing the changes with `git push heroku master`?

Comment: yes i commited, as well pushed my changes to master

Comment: Sorry, just to be totally clear about the commands you're running: `git push heroku master`, `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: @Ali please post the following files: `Gemfile`, `config/application.rb`, `config/boot.rb`, `config/environment.rb`. It seems like it's an error loading the `mysql2` gem

Comment: I  have added the files you asked for

Comment: I have posted all those files, that you asked for

Comment: @Ali I updated the answer with a solution that worked for me after reproducing your error. hope it helps